# Bug on the "tenacious" badge page

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

On the [tenacious badge page](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/225/tenacious):

[image]

Comment: Looks like this page was erroneously set to "awarded for a specific post" mode. The [Unsung Hero page](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/226/unsung-hero), on the other hand, works just fine. Good call!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason type was indeed set incorrectly after the badge revamp - it'll be corrected in the next build.